# Create parse a dictionary to another format

Tags: python

I wanted to parse a dictionary with a format. Currently this dictionary has the same user ID in separate dictionaries and I wanted to make it same user ID in one dictionary with key and values.

Below is my current dictionary:

```py
current_directory = {
    "key1": {
        "userID1": 5,
        "userID2": 1,
        "userID3": 5
    },
    "key2": {
        "userID1": 13,
        "userID2": 24,
        "userID3": 0
    },
    "key3": {
        "userID1": 14,
        "userID2": 12,
        "userID3": 3
    }
    # ...
}
```

Expected dictionary:

```py
parsed_directory = {
   "userID1": {
        "key1": 5,
        "key2": 13,
        "key3": 14
    },
   "userID2": {
        "key1": 1,
        "key2": 24,
        "key3": 3
    },
   "userID3": {
        "key1": 5,
        "key2": 0,
        "key3": 3
    }
   # ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possible example how you can transform the dictionary:

```py
original_dictionary = {
    "key1": {"userID1": 5, "userID2": 1, "userID3": 5},
    "key2": {"userID1": 13, "userID2": 24, "userID3": 0},
    "key3": {"userID1": 14, "userID2": 12, "userID3": 3},
}

parsed_dictionary = {}
for k, v in original_dictionary.items():
    for kk, vv in v.items():
        parsed_dictionary.setdefault(kk, {})[k] = vv

print(parsed_dictionary)
```

Prints:

```
{
    "userID1": {"key1": 5, "key2": 13, "key3": 14},
    "userID2": {"key1": 1, "key2": 24, "key3": 12},
    "userID3": {"key1": 5, "key2": 0, "key3": 3},
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is available if you use Pandas:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pandas as pd

in = {
    "key1": {
        "userID1": 5,
        "userID2": 1,
        "userID3": 5
    },
    "key2": {
        "userID1": 13,
        "userID2": 24,
        "userID3": 0
    },
    "key3": {
        "userID1": 14,
        "userID2": 12,
        "userID3": 3
    }
}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(in)
out = df.T.to_dict()
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
{'userID1': {'key1': 5, 'key2': 13, 'key3': 14}, 'userID2': {'key1': 1, 'key2': 24, 'key3': 12}, 'userID3': {'key1': 5, 'key2': 0, 'key3': 3}}
```

This reads your dictionary into a Pandas dataframe, takes the transpose, and converts the transposed dataframe back to a Python dictionary.